# bash tools for parsing arguments

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I have a bash script that uses a few variables (call them `$foo` and `$bar`). Right now the script defines them at the top with hard coded values like this:

```
foo=fooDefault
bar=barDefault

....

# use $foo and $bar
```

What I want is to be able to use the script like any of these:

```
myscript              # use all defaults
myscript -foo=altFoo  # use default bar
myscript -bar=altBar  # use default foo
myscript -bar=altBar -foo=altFoo
```

An ideal solution would allow me to just list the variable that I want to check for flags for.

*Is there a reasonably nice way to do this?*

---

I've seen [`getopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) and I think it might do about 70% of what I'm looking for but I'm wondering if there is a tool or indium that builds on it or the like that gets the rest.

Comment: getopts is the best I have found to date.  It's a little idiosyncratic but works well for my needs.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options ? looks similar to what you need

Comment: @bobah: Very related, and in fact might be a building block to what I'm looking for, but I'm looking for something a bit more specialized. Also, I'm looking for a cut-n-paste solution as what I've got is good enough for now.

Comment: Make sure you're aware of the difference between the Bash builtin `getopts` (short options only) and the external executable [`getopt(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) (long and short options). [This page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) recommends avoiding the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval to do something close:

```
foo=fooDefault
bar=barDefault

for arg in "$@"; do
    eval ${arg}
done
```

This version doesn't bother with a leading dash, so you would run it as:

```
myscript foo=newvalue
```

**That said, a couple of words of caution.  Because we are using eval, the caller can inject any code/data they want into your script.  If you need your code to be secure, you are going to have to validate `${arg}` before you `eval` it.**

Also, this is not very elegant if you need to have spaces in your data as you will have to double quote them (once for the command line and a second time for the inner `eval`):

```
myscript foo='"with sapces"'
```