# How can I add a help method to a shell script?

Tags: unix, shell

How do I check if a `-h` attribute has been passed into a shell script?  I would like to display a help message when a user calls `myscript.sh -h`.

Comment: Relevant examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008125/shell-script-common-template

Answer (score 210, accepted):

here's an example for bash:

```
usage="$(basename "$0") [-h] [-s n] -- program to calculate the answer to life, the universe and everything

where:
    -h  show this help text
    -s  set the seed value (default: 42)"

seed=42
while getopts ':hs:' option; do
  case "$option" in
    h) echo "$usage"
       exit
       ;;
    s) seed=$OPTARG
       ;;
    :) printf "missing argument for -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2
       echo "$usage" >&2
       exit 1
       ;;
   \?) printf "illegal option: -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2
       echo "$usage" >&2
       exit 1
       ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

To use this inside a function:

- use `"$FUNCNAME"` instead of `$(basename "$0")`
- add `local OPTIND OPTARG` before calling `getopts`

Comment: I'm trying this inside a function, but when I try to run the function I get this error "basename: invalid option -- 'b'".
It looks like it's trying to pass "-bash" to `basename` with the leading dash.

Comment: imside a function use `"$FUNCNAME"` not `"$0"`. Also, add `local OPTIND OPTARG`

Comment: Thanks. `FUNCNAME` works. I have all my functions inside a single file, so this is perfect for extending them into something useful for others.

Comment: @sigur, make sure you quote `"$usage"` **every** place you use it.

Comment: What is the `shift $((OPTIND - 1))` for?

Comment: That will remove all the options from the positional parameters, so that $1 will be the first argument that follows the options. If you were writing a function for `ls`, and you typed `ls -l -a /` then $1 would be `/`

Answer (score 62):

The first argument to a shell script is available as the variable `$1`, so the simplest implementation would be

```
if [ "$1" == "-h" ]; then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` [somestuff]"
  exit 0
fi
```

But what anubhava said.

Comment: You should make a habit of wrapping the if in [[ ... ]] for conditionals to avoid a bad parsing of a variable, source: https://github.com/bahamas10/bash-style-guide#bashisms

Comment: Yes, although the OP didn't specify bash, and `[` is the POSIX-compliant version.

Comment: **Note - For using inside `function`:** You should replace `exit 0` with `return` if you don't want to terminate your shell after run your function. (I've done it before )

Answer (score 39):

here is a part I use it to start a VNC server

```
#!/bin/bash
start() {
echo "Starting vnc server with $resolution on Display $display"
#your execute command here mine is below
#vncserver :$display -geometry $resolution
}

stop() {
echo "Killing vncserver on display $display"
#vncserver -kill :$display
}

#########################
# The command line help #
#########################
display_help() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [option...] {start|stop|restart}" >&2
    echo
    echo "   -r, --resolution           run with the given resolution WxH"
    echo "   -d, --display              Set on which display to host on "
    echo
    # echo some stuff here for the -a or --add-options 
    exit 1
}

################################
# Check if parameters options  #
# are given on the commandline #
################################
while :
do
    case "$1" in
      -r | --resolution)
          if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
            resolution="$2"   # You may want to check validity of $2
          fi
          shift 2
          ;;
      -h | --help)
          display_help  # Call your function
          exit 0
          ;;
      -d | --display)
          display="$2"
           shift 2
           ;;

      -a | --add-options)
          # do something here call function
          # and write it in your help function display_help()
           shift 2
           ;;

      --) # End of all options
          shift
          break
          ;;
      -*)
          echo "Error: Unknown option: $1" >&2
          ## or call function display_help
          exit 1 
          ;;
      *)  # No more options
          break
          ;;
    esac
done

###################### 
# Check if parameter #
# is set too execute #
######################
case "$1" in
  start)
    start # calling function start()
    ;;
  stop)
    stop # calling function stop()
    ;;
  restart)
    stop  # calling function stop()
    start # calling function start()
    ;;
  *)
#    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}" >&2
     display_help

     exit 1
     ;;
esac
```

It's a bit weird that I placed the start stop restart in a separate case but it should work

Comment: if you give a empty option to -d; won't it infinite loop?

Comment: Why do you exit 1 in the helper function?

Answer (score 26):

### For a quick single option solution, use `if`

If you only have a single option to check and it will always be the first option (`$1`) then the simplest solution is an `if` with a test (`[`). For example:

```
if [ "$1" == "-h" ] ; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` [-h]"
    exit 0
fi
```

Note that for posix compatibility `=` will work as well as `==`.

##### Why quote `$1`?

The reason the `$1` needs to be enclosed in quotes is that if there is no `$1` then the shell will try to run `if [  == "-h" ]` and fail because `==` has only been given a single argument when it was expecting two:

```
$ [ == "-h" ]
bash: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

### For anything more complex use `getopt` or `getopts`

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5476278/42473) [by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5474756/42473) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5474764/42473), if you have more than a single simple option, or need your option to accept an argument, then you should definitely go for the extra complexity of using `getopts`.

As a quick reference, I like [The 60 second getopts tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120409221849/http://bashcurescancer.com/the-60-second-getopts-tutorial.html).<sup>†</sup>

You may also want to consider the [`getopt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt#Shell) program instead of the built in shell [`getopts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopts). It allows the use of long options, and options *after* non option arguments (e.g. `foo a b c --verbose` rather than just `foo -v a b c`). [This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948533/42473) explains how to use GNU `getopt`.

<sup>† [jeffbyrnes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133479/jeffbyrnes) mentioned that the [original link](http://swik.net/Unix/BASH+Cures+Cancer+Blog/The+60+second+getopts+tutorial/bqll3) died but thankfully the [way back machine](https://archive.org/web/) had archived it.</sup>

Comment: Thanks!  I have been happily using getopts for a year now, but I'll have a look at getopt too.

Comment: Sadly, the link to The 60 Second getopts Tutorial is dead; it seems that bashcurescancer.com is no more. Here's a link to the [Wayback Machine's version](https://web.archive.org/web/20120409221849/http://bashcurescancer.com/the-60-second-getopts-tutorial.html).

Comment: The 60 seconds getopts tutorial is GOLD

Answer (score 8):

There's a simple way to implement this without `getopt` or `getopts`:

```sh
display_help() {
    # taken from https://stackoverflow.com/users/4307337/vincent-stans
    echo "Usage: $0 [option...] {start|stop|restart}" >&2
    echo
    echo "   -r, --resolution           run with the given resolution WxH"
    echo "   -d, --display              Set on which display to host on "
    echo
    # echo some stuff here for the -a or --add-options 
    exit 1
}

log() {
    echo "This is a log"
}
while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
        -h|--help) display_help; shift ;;
        -l|--log) log; shift ;;
        # ... (same format for other required arguments)
        *) echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1" ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: Great ! the simplest answer I found on stackoverflow, allows to custom your params easily. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Better to use getopt facility of bash. Please look at this Q&A for more help: [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a super-compact, yet readable way to add basic help based on @zeb's version. It handles both of the commonly used `-h` and `--help` flags.

```sh
[ "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "--help" ] && echo "
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
  aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
  voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
" && exit
```

The result looks like this:

```
$ ./myscript.sh -h

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
  aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
  voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

$ _
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use case for this...

```
case $1 in 
 -h) echo $usage ;; 
  h) echo $usage ;;
help) echo $usage ;;
esac
```