# Converting Bash command line options to variable name

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that takes in an option.
Lets call these options A and B.

In the script A and B may or may not be defined as variables.

I want to be able to check if the variable is defined or not.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
if [ ! -n $1 ]; then 
   echo "Error"
fi
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this question help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way to test whether a variable is set is to use the `+` expansion option.  You'll see this a lot in `configure` scripts:

```
if test -s "${foo+set}"
```

where `${foo+set}` expands to `"set"` if it is set or `""` if it's not.  This allows for the variable to be set but empty, if you need it.  `${foo:+set}` additionally requires `$foo` to not be empty.

(That `$(eval echo $a)` thing has problems:  it's slow, and it's vulnerable to code injection (!).)

Oh, and if you just want to throw an error if something required isn't set, you can just refer to the variable as `${foo:?}` (leave off the `:` if set but empty is permissible), or for a custom error message `${foo:?Please specify a foo.}`.

Comment: I like this, and [P.E.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) is nice. Just wanted to mention here too, that bash v4+ (iirc) provides the `-v` test, as mentioned in my answer, to denote if a variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it that way, try this:

```
if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    echo "Error"
fi
```

The error in your version is actually the lack of **quoting**.
Should be:

```
if [ ! -n "$1" ]; then
    echo "Error"
fi
```

But you don't need the negation, use `-z` instead.

If you work on Bash, then use double brackets `[[` `]]` too.

from the `man bash` page:

> ```
>  -z string
>       True if the length of string is zero.
>  -n string
>       True if the length of string is non-zero.
> ```

Also, if you use bash v4 or greater (`bash --version`) there's `-v`

> ```
>  -v varname
>       True if the shell variable varname is set (has been assigned a value).
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You did not define how these options should be passed in, but I think:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
   echo "Error"
   exit 1
fi
```

is what you are looking for.

However, if some of these options are, err, optional, then you might want something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
USAGE="$0: [-a] [--alpha] [-b type] [--beta file] [-g|--gamma] args..."

ARGS=`POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 getopt -n "$0" -s bash -o ab:g -l alpha,beta:,gamma -- "$@"`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
 then
  echo "$USAGE" >&2
  exit 1
 fi
eval set -- "$ARGS"
unset ARGS

while true
 do
  case "$1" in
   -a) echo "Option a"; shift;;
   --alpha) echo "Option alpha"; shift;;
   -b) echo "Option b, arg '$2'"; shift 2;;
   --beta) echo "Option beta, arg '$2'"; shift 2;;
   -g|--gamma) echo "Option g or gamma"; shift;;
   --) shift ; break ;;
    *) echo "Internal error!" ; exit 1 ;;
  esac
 done

echo Remaining args
for arg in "$@"
 do
  echo '--> '"\`$arg'"
 done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is "$1", i.e.

```
root@root:~# cat auto.sh
Usage () {

        echo "error"
}
if [ ! -n $1 ];then
        Usage
        exit 1
fi
root@root:~# bash auto.sh
root@root:~# cat auto2.sh
Usage () {

        echo "error"
}
if [ ! -n "$1" ];then
        Usage
        exit 1
fi
root@root:~# bash auto2.sh
error
```