# Passing Quoted Posix Argument Values in bash

Tags: bash, unix, posix, quotes

I have a bash script where I'm trying to pass posix style arguments with quoted values down to another script called within. On the command-line I might type:

```
somescript --foo="bar baz"
```

This means with the argument having the key `foo`, the value is `bar baz`. Within somescript, you might think this would work:

```
innerscript "$@"
```

However, this re-quotes the *entirety* of each argument, both key and value chunked together, not just the value. So innerscript receives `"--foo=bar baz"` and believes you are trying to pass the key named `foo=bar baz` with an *empty value*.

It's not good enough to tell bash "re-quote all the passed in arguments". I need to tell bash "re-quote all passed in arguments *exactly how they were quoted before*". Don't change the position of my quotes, bro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `innerscript`, then.  There is no difference between:

```
innerscript --foo="bar baz"
innerscript "--foo=bar baz"
innerscript --foo=bar\ baz
innerscript --foo=bar' 'baz
```

or, undoubtedly, a number of other alternatives.  Inside `innerscript`, `$1` (in shell notation) contains just 13 characters: `--foo=bar baz`.  Incidentally, the same holds for `somescript`; when you invoke it as shown, it does not see the double quotes.  They are handled by (and removed by) the shell.

To see this, try:

```
echo --foo="bar baz"
```

Comment: The problem was with my understanding of innerscript. You were right. It did not have completely position-independent options like I thought it did.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

Scripts receive arguments. When the shell *parses* that line, it passes the first argument as:
"--foo=bar baz". You cannot do anything to prevent that. But I don't see why that causing any problems, you can split the argument based on `=`.

```
# function test { echo $1; }
# test a"b""c"'d'\e
abcde
```

Answer (score 0):

For parsing arguments and options use `getopt` command.

Note1: `getopt` (gnu command) is enhanced `getopts` (defined in POSIX).

Note2: `--long-options` are GNU-style, not POSIX

Comment: See [Using getopts in bash script to get long and short command line options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/402413#402413).