# How do you use getopts?

Tags: bash, getopts

what is the easiest, most straight forward, way to use **getopts** in **bash** script.

if i have a script called: **myscript** and it **CAN** take the the arguments: **-p -r -s -x**

```
if argument x then exit
if argument p then echo "port 10"
if argument s then add 2+2
if argument r then echo env
```

This is a hypothetical script but I would just like to see an example of how this would be done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)

Comment: I seen it, didnt help me. Thanks for pointing that out though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
while getopts :xpsr opt; do
   case $opt in
     x ) exit                                ;;
     p ) echo port 10                        ;;
     s ) (( 2 + 2 ))                         ;;
     r ) echo env                            ;;
    \? ) echo "${0##*/}" [ -xpsr ]; exit 1   ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: sweet.. thanks Dimitre. But what does this last part do? \? ) echo "${0##*/}" [ -xpsr ]; exit 1

Comment: Prints the usage and exists if an invalid option is passed.

Comment: No, I don't (perhaps I'm reading the questions too literally :)).
Neither do I show how to deal with options' arguments ...

Answer (score 3):

```
usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $0 [-o <offset>] [-h];"
    exit 0;
}

# -o (offset) need a value
# -h prints help
offset=0    # 0 is default offset

while getopts o:s opt
do
    case "$opt" in
    d)  offset="$OPTARG";; # changing offset
    s)  usage              # calls function "usage"
    \?) echo "$OPTARG is an unknown option"
        exit 1;; # all other options
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Comment: In which shell does that `shift $OPTIND-1` expression work?  It normally has to be something like `$(($OPTIND - 1))`, doesn't it.

Comment: Or even: `$((OPTIND - 1))`, which is now standard.