# why the getopt doesn't work well in my mac os?

Tags: shell, getopt

In bash: I input the command：

```
getopt -l name,data -- --namd
```

and the output is

```
-- name,pp -- --namd
```

input :

```
getopt -l name,data -- --name
```

the output alse

```
-- name,pp -- --name
```

why it dosen't tell me the err when i input `getopt -l name,data -- --namd`?

Comment: You may also want to look at the `getopts` builtin command, which is generally easier to work with.  At least, I think so.

Comment: Thanks @H2CO3, I'm a new hand here~~~~~

Comment: @larsks, but I want to deal the long parameter. such as: cmd --path /user  --name qiushuitian -d -p 100

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that on the mac, getopt is the BSD based getopt, rather than the gnu-based getopt.

It doesn't understand long options. It's not that it 'doesn't work well', it's that it's not designed to do what you asked.

Comment: Thanks. But if I want to deal with the long options, how can I do? Must I analyze the parameter myself?

Comment: You can install gnu getopt from macports - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options

Comment: There is a homebrew formula also: `brew install gnu-getopt` works too.