# How can I make bash deal with long param using "getopt" command in mac?

Tags: macos, bash, gnu

I want to make my bash script deal with long parameters. I found `getopt`, but it isn't supported in OS X. Can anyone tell me why `getopt` was implemented by BSD, but not GNU? 
I tried building `getopt` in GNU C lib, but it failed for my poor skills with Linux.

Did anyone do this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)

Answer (score 33):

There is a [brew bottle for getopt](http://brewformulas.org/Gnu-getopt).

Just run `brew install gnu-getopt`.

You can either specify the path for it like
`/usr/local/Cellar/gnu-getopt/1.1.6/bin/getopt`

Or use `brew link --force gnu-getopt` so it will be linked in `/usr/local/bin/`

Just be aware that forcing linking might be corrupting your system (as it replaces the system getopt by the gnu one).

See maybe later answer suggesting to define `FLAGS_GETOPT_CMD` (though few comments state issues with it).

Comment: If you want to use the `g`-prefix that `brew` uses for other GNU coreutils, you can add this to your `.bash_profile`:   `if [[ -x /usr/local/Cellar/gnu-getopt/1.1.6/bin/getopt ]] ;    then   alias ggetopt=/usr/local/Cellar/gnu-getopt/1.1.6/bin/getopt;    fi`

Comment: I can't link it, it dumps `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-getopt/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`. I ran the command and it still dump the same thing. Any advice?

Comment: I got the same message about using the echo command... after running it, you have to either restart your terminal or you should be able to run `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: Aliases cann't be used in script, so `cd /usr/local/bin/` and `ln -s $(brew --prefix)/opt/gnu-getopt/bin/getopt ggetopt`, then I can use it via `ggetopt` in both of command line and shell script.

Answer (score 22):

I recommend using Homebrew to install `gnu-getopt` and then adding `$FLAGS_GETOPT_CMD` to your `~/.bash_profile` file to specify the cmd path for getopt, pointing at the homebrew location, like so:

```
brew install gnu-getopt
```

Then follow directions from brew to add to your local path:

```
sudo echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-getopt/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you can add `FLAGS_GETOPT_CMD`:

```
sudo echo 'export FLAGS_GETOPT_CMD="$(brew --prefix gnu-getopt)/bin/getopt"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Open a new terminal, or run `. ~/.bash_profile` in existing terminal to load changes

Run `echo $FLAGS_GETOPT_CMD` to confirm it was actually set in your console

Comment: I love how people downvote but provide ZERO comments as to why ... tsk tsk

Comment: this is just not working, maybe that's the reason of downvoting

Comment: @denu probably bc of user error and not opening a new console or calling `. ~/.bash_profile` ... it works fine i just tested it on latest OSX ... and you can find numerous tutorials and comments online using it as well https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/98 as example

Comment: This doesn't work because it doesn't set the path. When you install gnu-getopt, brew tells you to do this:
"If you need to have gnu-getopt first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-getopt/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile"
This works, because it sets it first in your path.

Comment: @StevenPeterson ah yeah i assumed users would follow brew instructions, added to post for clarification, thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: I don't understand what setting FLAGS_GETOPT_CMD does in practice? Who or what cares to look at the FLAGS_GETOPT_CMD environment variable when calling getopt?

Comment: @NathanBell it sets the brew based gnu-getopt to be used for getopt command

Comment: This did not work for me. @sMyles. I've created a post about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76519264/how-can-i-get-gnu-getopt-correctly-installed-on-macos)

Answer (score 3):

It's generally a better idea to use `getopts` instead, and stick with short options.  You can see getopts in action in [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/402377/1072112).  Short options are more standard throughout OSX command line tools, and consistency is a good thing.

Also, getopts is built in to bash, so it's definitely available in OSX, as well as every other platform that can run bash.

Note that there is a `getopt` is also available in OSX.  From Terminal, type `man getopt` to see its documentation.  It doesn't support long options.  This is a good reason not to use long options when you're writing tools to run on OSX.

If you want to do this anyway, you can install `getopt` from [macports](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=getopt).  Alternately, if you want better portability, you can roll your own long argument handling.

Post some code, and we'll help debug it.

Comment: Short options tend to be unreadable, especially if there are lot of them. Perfectly reasonable to want to use them.

Comment: What is "a good reason not to use long options when you're writing tools" ?

Comment: @jalanb, lack of support for long options in OSX would seem to be a good reason not to use long options when writing shell tools for OSX.

Comment: Maybe is good reason not to use a Macintosh.   Seems more reasonable to expect Mac users to get GNU getopt than to assume rest of GNU-based world do without long args.