# How to write user defined options in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)

This is the code i've written

```
#! /bin/bash

getopts master $1

while getopts ":master" opt; do
  case $opt in
    master)
      echo "-master was triggered! $1 was entered" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

and this is the output i'm getting-

```
]$ ./test123.sh -master 123
./test123.sh: line 3: getopts: `-master': not a valid identifier
```

How do i define a user defined option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are a couple of problems.

1. I don't understand what this (`getopts master $1`) is doing and you can remove it
2. I think you need single char arguments (i.e. -m vs -master)

e.g. the below seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":m" opt; do
  case $opt in
    m)
      echo "-m was triggered! $1 was entered" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: when i run the script the output i get is `-m was triggered! -m was entered`, but i want the output to be `-m was triggered! 123 was entered`

Comment: got it. i must writ it as `echo "-m was triggered! $2 was entered" >&2`