# Bash doesn't parse quotes when converting a string to arguments

Tags: string, bash, arguments, spaces, quoting

This is my problem. In bash 3:

```
$ test='One "This is two" Three'
$ set -- $test
$ echo $2
"This
```

How to get bash to understand the quotes and return $2 as `This is two` and not `"This`? Unfortunately I cannot alter the construction of the variable called `test` in this example.

Comment: This is also exhaustively covered in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason this happens is because of the order in which the shell parses the command line: it parses (and removes) quotes and escapes, then replaces variable values. By the time `$test` gets replaced with `One "This is two" Three`, it's too late for the quotes to have their intended effect.

The simple (but dangerous) way to do this is by adding another level of parsing with `eval`:

```
$ test='One "This is two" Three'
$ eval "set -- $test"
$ echo "$2"
This is two
```

(Note that the quotes in the `echo` command are not necessary, but are a good general practice.)

The reason I say this is dangerous is that it doesn't just go back and reparse for quoted strings, it goes back and reparses *everything*, maybe including things you didn't want interpreted like command substitutions. Suppose you had set

```
$ test='One `rm /some/important/file` Three'
```

...`eval` will actually run the `rm` command. So if you can't count on the contents of `$test` to be "safe", **do not use this construct**.

BTW, the right way to do this sort of thing is with an array:

```
$ test=(One "This is two" Three)
$ set -- "${test[@]}"
$ echo "$2"
This is two
```

Unfortunately, this requires control of how the variable is created.

Answer (score 6):

Now we have bash 4 where it's possible to do something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

function qs_parse() { 
    readarray -t "$1" < <( printf "%s" "$2"|xargs -n 1 printf "%s\n" ) 
}

tab='   '  # tabulation here
qs_parse test "One 'This is two' Three -n 'foo${tab}bar'"

printf "%s\n" "${test[0]}"
printf "%s\n" "${test[1]}"
printf "%s\n" "${test[2]}"
printf "%s\n" "${test[3]}"
printf "%s\n" "${test[4]}"
```

Outputs, as expected:

```
One
This is two
Three
-n
foo     bar  # tabulation saved
```

Actually, I am not sure but it's probably possible to do that in older bash like that:

```
function qs_parse() {
    local i=0
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        parsed_str[i]="${line}"
        let i++
    done < <( printf "%s\n" "$1"|xargs -n 1 printf "%s\n" )
}

tab='   ' # tabulation here
qs_parse "One 'This is two' Three -n 'foo${tab}bar'"

printf "%s\n" "${parsed_str[0]}"
printf "%s\n" "${parsed_str[1]}"
printf "%s\n" "${parsed_str[2]}"
printf "%s\n" "${parsed_str[3]}"
printf "%s\n" "${parsed_str[4]}"
```

Comment: The use of `echo` adds some bugs here, `echo` with an unquoted argument doubly so. If `$t=$'\t'; qs_parse "One \"*\" -n \"tab${t}between${t}each${t}word\""`, you don't want those tabs turned to spaces, or the `-n` treated as an argument to `echo`. Consider `printf '%s\n' "$1"` instead.

Comment: @Grief, would you accept an edit making the changes I proposed previously?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry for not doing that earlier, but I've updated the answer. It appears that echo must be replaced with printf everywhere to make '-n' work. Hope you like the answer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this problem is to use xargs (eval free).
It retains double quoted strings together:

```
$ test='One "This is two" Three'
$ IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(xargs -n1 <<<"$test") )
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
<One>
<This is two>
<Three>
```

Of course, you can set the positional arguments with that array:

```
$ set -- "${arr[@]}"
$ echo "$2"
This is two
```

Comment: `xargs` is the right tool for the job, definitely. Unquoted expansion, not so much. If you have `test='One "This is two" Three "*"'`, you don't want the `*` replaced with a list of filenames.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You don't expect a quoted `*` to be expanded, do you.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, problem is that `arr=( $(...) )` is expanding the results of `$(...)` is an _unquoted_ context, so even if it's quoted in the `...` command, it gets expanded during the substitution operation later. Why don't you actually _test_ the code I was complaining about, rather than merely implying that the complaint was unfounded?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, ...see the above demonstrated in https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/UncomfortableIllDecompiler#main.sh

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I misunderstood your first message -- I thought that it's not expanded while you expect it to (so there was no reason for me to check it). Thanks for the explanation and the demo, I see it now.

Comment: What is the purpose of setting `IFS` to `\n`?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a couple native bash functions to do this: https://github.com/mblais/bash_ParseFields

You can use the `ParseFields` function like this:

```
$ str='field1 field\ 2 "field 3"'
$ ParseFields -d "$str" a b c d
$ printf "|%s|\n|%s|\n|%s|\n|%s|\n" "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d"
|field1|         
|field 2|
|field 3|
||
```

The `-d` option to ParseFields removes any surrounding quotes and interprets backslashes from the parsed fields.

There is also a simpler `ParseField` function (used by `ParseFields`) that parses a single field at a specific offset within a string.

Note that these functions cannot parse a *stream*, only a string. The IFS variable can also be used to specify field delimiters besides whitespace.

If you require that unescaped apostrophes may appear in *unquoted* fields, that would require a minor change - let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
test='One "This is two" Three'
mapfile -t some_args < <(xargs -n1 <<<"$test")
echo "'${some_args[0]}'" "'${some_args[1]}'" "'${some_args[2]}'"
```

output: 
'One' 'This is two' 'Three'