# Assigning a bash variable to be a list of two word strings

Tags: bash, for-loop, variable-assignment

I want to assign a bash variable to be a collection of two word segments. The bash variable is similar to a list of strings, where each string is two separate words enclosed within quotation marks). I am then trying to use this variable within a for loop so that the loop variable is assigned to one of the two word segments each iteration.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
variable='"var one" "var two" "var three"'
for i in $variable
do
   echo $i
done
```

The output I would like is :

```
var one
var two
var three
```

But what I am getting at the moment in

```
"var
one"
"var
two"
"var
three"
```

Comment: Why not use an array?

Comment: You're putting a list of strings into a string. Why not put a list of strings into a *list* -- or, rather, an array?

Comment: Related: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- strings can't be safely used to store lists for the same reason they can't be used to store commands.

Comment: @Inian Yeah that's the answer, I didn't know how to loop through arrays in bash, and I didn't know much about bash arrays in general

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define a single three-element array, not a 31-character string:

```
variable=(
  "var one"
  "var two"
  "var three"
)
for i in "${variable[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

If you need to accept a string as input and parse it into an array while honoring quotes in the data, we have other questions directly on-point; see for instance [Bash doesn't parse quotes when converting a string to arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857027/bash-doesnt-parse-quotes-when-converting-a-string-to-arguments)