# bash shell script getting substring from particular line in file that is delimited by double quotes

Tags: json, bash, shell, substring

I am trying to get a substring from a line in a file using a shell script. The sticky part is the line in the file is delimited by double quotes. I'm trying to get the string that represents a version number that is between the second set of double quotes.

This is the line in my file:

`"parentDirectory/childLibrary": "2.4.177"`

I'm trying to extract `2.4.177` and store it in a variable so I can use it later on in my shell script.

Here is my shell script so far:

`currentVersion=$(grep '\"parentDirectory/childLibrary\": \"' somefile.txt)`

this gets the line that has the version number in it that I want to work with, but I can't figure out how to get what is between the 3rd and 4th double quotes in the string. I can't just say take `x` amount of characters starting at position `y` because I don't know how long the substring will be. The closest thing I've found is the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857027/bash-doesnt-parse-quotes-when-converting-a-string-to-arguments) but I can't figure out how to use this to set a variable equal to the substring I want it to. Any help would be much appreciated. As always, a working answer that is explained clearly will be upvoted and marked as selected answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this is a JSON file that you are trying to parse? Download and setup a syntax aware parser like `jq` instead of line oriented tools `grep`

Comment: Yes this is a JSON file but my situation requires that I have to use a shell script to accomplish what I need to do because of the total scope of what I am doing.

Comment: See [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1955505/5291015)

Comment: After grep, `currentVersion=$( echo $currentVersion | tr - d '"' ) `. This will delete `"` in the line. After this `currentVersion=${currentVersion##*: } `. I am currently on my phone so can't test it. I don't remember exactly which one to use (#, ##, %, %%). But you can solve with similar approach.

Comment: If your "total scope" doesn't allow you to use the right tool for the job, I'd take a step back and rethink your approach, to be honest.

Comment: @tripleee I understand that there are unix tools for parsing JSON files, but with my shell script I am creating I'm doing more than just parsing a JSON file, so I need to be able to get a substring from my JSON file but I need to do a lot more than that in my shell script. Please remove the `Marked as duplicate` so I can get an answer to my question

Comment: Several of the answers in the duplicate show exactly how to use Bash alone or standard Unix utilities like Awk or `sed` to extract information from JSON. You really need to show how this is not a duplicate, or perhaps specify precisely which part *after* the actual extraction isn't obvious.

Comment: Trivially `awk -F '"' '{ print $4 }' file` extracts the string between the third and fourth double quote on a line. Factoring your regex into the Awk script should be another 5 seconds of effort. (Hint: http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)