# getopts treats an option as argument of a previous one

Tags: bash, getopts

I've the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="NONE"
LOST=0
AVG=0

while getopts ":pmu:" OPTION; do
    case $OPTION in
        u)
            USER=$OPTARG
            ;;
        p)
            LOST=1
            ;;
        m)
            AVG=1
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "Invalid argument: -$OPTARG"
            exit 1
            ;;
        :)
            echo "-$OPTARG requires an argument."
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "$USER-$LOST-$AVG"

exit 0
```

I want the `-u` option to take an argument. The script correctly recognizes invalid options and when `-u` is called without an argument. But unfortunately, when I type:

`myscript -u -m -p`

It prints:

`-m-1-0`

So, it uses `-m` as `-u` argument and ignores the `-m` option itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) that the `-u` option was followed by an option-argument.  `-m` is a string value; the fact that it starts with a `-` sign is immaterial to its status as an option-argument; you are allowed to use `-` at the start of an option-argument value.

So, your observations are correct.  That is the intended design; this is the way the [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) function works, and it is an implementation of the POSIX [Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) — a slightly relaxed version of those guidelines, in fact.  If you don't like it, use something else other than `getopts`, but you'll be fighting against the system.

Note that although POSIX `getopt()` allows 'optional option-arguments' in theory, in practice, only the last option on the command line can have an optional option-argument, making them essentially useless.

It is perfectly possible to devise option parsing systems that behave differently and which substantially satisfy the Utility Syntax Guidelines; many people have done it. Indeed, the GNU [`getopt`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/getopt/) program is an extended implementation which is likely what you should be looking at — but it has a very different invocation to get to the behaviour (see also [Using `getopts` in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/)).  The systems are all different, and it is usually complex to describe the required option handling behaviour succinctly yet unambiguously.  See [Solaris CLIP — Command Line Interface Paradigm](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/Intro/) for more information<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>* Google search term 'solaris clip' gets you movie clips for the movie 'Solaris'.  A working search term is 'Solaris command line interface paradigm'.</sup>

Comment: So, `getopts` may help me only if `-u` is always used as last argument?

Comment: That isn't the way I'd interpret it.  If you have a `-u` option on the command line, you said it must be followed by an option-argument.  If you want `-u` optionally followed by an option-argument, then `getopts` isn't really the tool to use; it does not support optional option-arguments.  You should probably look to GNU `getopt`, mentioned in an update to my answer.