# Bash multiple combinations in getopts

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to make a script where you can give a couple of parameters with it:

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered
      ;;
    b)
      echo "-b was triggered
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

The code I have now works but the problem I have is that I want to give another function/echo if it combines.

Example:
When I do: `.MyScript -ab` than it should give another function that what is defined in `a` or in `b`

so a bit like:

```
ab) -> Script -a -b or Script -ab 
 echo "-ab was triggered"
```

What is the best solution to do this?
Any ideas, your free to post!

Comment: This won't run as every arg needs an additional arg (e.g. `-a file -b file2`). If there is no additional arg, do not add `:` after the letter!

Comment: I suggest you do not mix the original one letter end the extended (multiple letters) arguments. Use `--ab` instead of `-ab`.

Comment: Yes but my problem is, how do I put the multiple solutions in my case?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/402377/1630171).

Comment: ...and the Oscar goes to???

Answer (score 1):

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered"
      a_val=$OPTARG
      ;;
    b)
      echo "-b was triggered"
      b_val=$OPTARG
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
if [[ -n $a_val ]]; then do something with "$a_val"; fi
if [[ -n $b_val ]]; then do something with "$b_val"; fi
```

The only situation this may cause confusion is if the user passes `-a ""` -- one workaround is:

```
a=false
b=false
while getopts ":a:b:c:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a) echo "-a was triggered"; a_val=$OPTARG; a=true ;;
    b) echo "-b was triggered"; b_val=$OPTARG; b=true ;;
  esac
done
if $a; then do something with "$a_val"; fi
if $b; then do something with "$b_val"; fi
```

Here, there are no brackets: `if $a; then ...` because I'm invoking the *command* "true" or "false" and acting on that exit status.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

You can use the [getopt(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) linux utility. This is not a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) internal function, but this can handle long arguments.

Try this:

```
declare -A OPTARG
GetOpt() {
  local prog="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
  [ $# -eq 0 ] && echo "$prog: Bad call of GetOpts">&2 && exit 1
  local longopt="$1"
  shift

  local tmp
  tmp=$(getopt -n"$prog" -a -l "$longopt" -- '' "$@") || exit
  eval "tmp=($tmp)"

  local i
  for((i=0;i<${#tmp[*]};++i)){
    key=${tmp[i]#--}
    [ -z "$key" ] && break
    if [[ "${tmp[i+1]}" =~ ^-- ]]; then OPTARG[$key]=1
    else OPTARG[$key]="${tmp[++i]}"
    fi
  }
  for((j=0;++i<${#tmp[*]};++j)){ OPTFILE[j]=${tmp[i]};}
}

GetOpt "a b ab file:" "$@"

[ "${OPTARG[a]}" -a "${OPTARG[b]}" ] && OPTARG[ab]=1 && unset OPTARG[a] OPTARG[b]

[ "${OPTARG[a]}" ] && echo Do a
[ "${OPTARG[b]}" ] && echo Do b
[ "${OPTARG[ab]}" ] && echo Do ab
```

The defined `GetOpt` function will place the parsed command line argument with the checked long options to the associative array called `OPTARG`. If there is an error it will fail informing about the problem.

With `getopt`'s `-a` option you can use `-ab` or `--ab` format. Keep in mind that if You have `del` defined, then the `-d` option (if `-d` is not specified) will expand to `--del`.

If You specify an arg with additional option it can contain spaces. E.g. if `-l file:` defined in `getopt` then it can be used as `./test --file="q w"`. `${OPTARG[file]}` will be `q w`.

The `OPTFILE` array contains the optional arguments (args given after `--`).

Comment: This works good but is it possible to refer to --ab if I want to run my script like this: . MyScript -a -b ?

Comment: @user2252399: Sure! In the `case` `-a` check `$2` whether it is `-b`. If it is, then do what You want for `--ab` (and do a shift to remove `-b` from command line)..

Comment: @user2252399: Or You can check after the `while-loop` that both `-a` and `-b` options is set (see env.var `a` and `b`). It yes, set the variable `ab` and clear `a` and `b`.

Comment: @user2252399: I reduced the code a little bit and I added the handling of both `-a` and `-b`. Pls check!

Comment: @user2252399: More complete version. Does not modifies command line arguments, stops if bad args were passed and handles opt.args with spaces.

Comment: One major problem with the linux getopt utility is that there's a traditional-UNIX getopt utility that has completely different usage and is generally unsafe-by-design, so using it locks one into Linux platforms in particular (and leads to surprising bugs when a script gets run on a platform that has the other, more traditional getopt instead). See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing