# Accessing shell script arguments by index

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, scripting

I'm sure this is a no-brainer when you're into shell programming.
Unfortunately I'm not and I'm having a pretty hard time ...

I need to verify arguments passed to a shell script.
I also want to store all parameters passed in an array as I need further separation later.

I have an argument "-o" which must be followed by either 0 or 1.
Thus, I want to check if the following argument is valid.
Here's what I tried:

```
# Loop over all arguments
for i in "$@"
do
    # Check if there is a "-" as first character,
    # if so: it's a parameter
    str="$i"
    minus=${str:0:1}

    # Special case: -o is followed by 0 or 1
    # this parameter needs to be added, too
    if [ "$str" == "-o" ]
    then
        newIdx=`echo $((i+1))`   # <-- problem here: how can I access the script param by a generated index?
        par="$($newIdx)"

        if [[ "$par" != "0" || "$par" != "1" ]]
        then
            echo "script error: The -o parameter needs to be followed by 0 or 1"
            exit -1
        fi
        paramIndex=$((paramIndex+1))

    elif [ "$minus" == "-" ]
    then
        myArray[$paramIndex]="$i"
        paramIndex=$((paramIndex+1))
    fi
done
```

I tried various things but it didn't work ...
Would be grateful if someone could shed light on this!

Thanks

Comment: might be easier with a `while`-loop and `shift`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `bash`, you can use indirect parameter expansion to access an arbitrary positional parameter.

```
$ set a b c
$ paramIndex=2
$ echo $2
b
$ echo ${!paramIndex}
b
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to access next argument in `for`.

1. How about to rewriting your script to use  [getopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)?
2. If you don't like getopt, try to rewrite your script using `shift`:

```
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
  str="$1"
  minus=${str:0:1}
  if [ "$str" == "-o" ]
  then
    shift
    par="$1"
#  ...
  elif [ "$minus" == "-" ]
  then
    # append element into array
    myArray[${#myArray[@]}]="$str"
  fi

  shift
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it in a minute. What confuses me: I can access each argument using $1, $2..., but it seems I can't do $parNum when parNum is a simple variable somewhere in the shell script. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know any method to access argument value by index that is stored in variable. But you can copy arguments into some variable and access it values as usual: `i=2;  args=("$@");  echo "${args[$i]}"`

Comment: I second the recommendation to use either `getopts` (the `bash` built-in) or `getopt` (the external program).

Comment: @loentar: And thanks for the "append to array" trick. Just using it ;-)

Comment: @guitarflow: There's an easier way to append to an array: `myArray+=("$str")` -- be sure to include the parentheses, or it'll append to the first element rather than adding a new element to the array.

Comment: Use `=`, not `==`, in `test` comparisons; only the former operator is POSIX-specified, so the latter will break if the OP uses practices they learned here when writing code for `/bin/sh`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html