# Command line arguments versus case statement argument

Tags: shell, awk, command-line-arguments

I am trying to do a command, but I need to get a command line argument. Here is my problem:

This is the code:

```
pl_function(){
 node=$(echo "$1" | awk -F'\.' '{print $2}')
 echo $node
}
```

I have a case statement:

```
case "$1" in -pl.*)
 pl_function
  ;;
esac
```

When I run this, it prints a blank.

Also, I would like to include `getopts`, in order to not care about the order of the arguments. Let's say I have `-location` followed by an argument and `-grep` followed by argument and `-def_location` followed by no argument.

How can I use `getopts` in this case?

Comment: What about using functions with not reserved names? `my_function` can be harmless.

Comment: yeah sorry! its actually called pl_function

Comment: You have a [useless use of echo](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#echo) and you fail to properly quote the variable you `echo`. The function could be simply `echo "$1" | awk -F '\.' '{ print $2 }'` but see also @JohnKugelman's answer.

Comment: You should probably post a separate question about getopts. One question per question, please.

Comment: Even more simply, `pl_function () { node=${1#*.}; echo "${node%.*}"; }` (at least, no external processes are necessary).

Comment: While it works, that is the most eccentrically formatted `case` statement I've seen in a _long_ time.  The long option names won't work with `getopts`; you'll need to use GNU `getopt`. See [Using `getopts` in `bash` shell script to get long and short command-line options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/)

Comment: thank you for the help with getopt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i run this, it prints a blank.

It **would** because you do not pass any parameter to the function that *expects* one.  Replace your function call with

```
my_function "$1"
```

Moreover, as [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385628/command-line-arguments-versus-case-statement-argument#comment28730389_19385628) out by @fedorqui do not used [reserved words](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reserved-Word-Index.html) for variable/function names.

Comment: great!! that actually answers my question!! thank you

Answer (score 2):

Inside a function `$1`, `$2`, et al are the function's arguments. You need to explicitly pass the script's `$1` when you call a function.

```
case "$1" in -pl.*)
 pl_function "$1"
  ;;
```

Also, you could use a bit of shell script magic to do the string splitting instead of invoking awk:

```
node=${1#*.}    # `#*.' removes a substring matching `*.' from the
                # front of $1
```

Comment: pl_function doesn't just print 1 in -pl.1, but it actually uses 1 in an if statement to execute other commands. I need the case statement, just to access the function pl_function when the user enters -pl.1 or -pl.2 etc

Comment: If there are more than two dot separated fields, you also need to do `"${1%%.*}"`. But +1, this is the way to do it.

Comment: that actually works too!! but it didnt solve the problem that it printed blank. My mistake was that i didn't pass arguments to the function.