# Code explanation required for a kornshell scripting novice

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I know java so the do while and case are no issue. I have read the man page for getopts. It has been of some use. Really im looking for plain english explanation of what is happening with    "getopts :d:p:nil optname"

```
while getopts :d:p:nil optname
do
 case $optname in
```

Comment: If you know java, see also http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/api/gnu/getopt/Getopt.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell script is invoked with a collection of arguments, like any other command on Unix.

The `getopts` built-in command helps parse those arguments, dividing them up into:

- Flags with no value associated with them
- Flags with a value associated with them
- Non-flag arguments (usually but not necessarily file names)

Given the loop:

```
while getopts :d:p:nil optname
```

the flags with no value associated with them are `-n`, `-i` and `-l`.  The flags which need a value are `-d` and `-p`.  The loop 
processes each of the flag arguments in the command line in turn.  The single letter for the option is stored in the shell variable `$optname`.  If the flag takes a value, then that is in `$OPTARG`.

The leading colon to the string defining the options says that `getopts` should not report errors, leaving that up to the script.

The `getopts` command returns success (0) when there was an option found; it returns failure (non-zero, probably 1) when there are no more options to process.

This can be because it came across an argument that didn't start with a dash, or because it came across the special marker argument `--`.

See also the [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) function in C programming.  The facilities of the shell are based on that.

There are extensions of various sorts to handle multi-letter option names.  See also [Using `getopts` in `bash` shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377).

Answer (score 0):

There should be some useful information in `help getopts`:

> getopts: getopts optstring name [arg]
>
> Parse option arguments.
>
> Getopts is used by shell procedures to parse positional parameters
>      as options.
>
> OPTSTRING contains the option letters to be recognized; if a letter
>      is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument,
>      which should be separated from it by white space.
>
> Each time it is invoked, getopts will place the next option in the
>      shell variable $name, initializing name if it does not exist, and
>      the index of the next argument to be processed into the shell
>      variable OPTIND.  OPTIND is initialized to 1 each time the shell or
>      a shell script is invoked.  When an option requires an argument,
>      getopts places that argument into the shell variable OPTARG.
>
> ...

Here `OPTSTRING` is the sequence `:d:p:nil` and `name` is called `optname`. The `case` statement will match against each different option while they are placed in `optstring`.