# putting - and -​- before switches in git commands

Tags: git

Why do we put `-` before some switches in git and `--` before others? Is there any rule of thumb to help you remember which one to use?

Comment: See [Single dashes `-` for single-character options, but double dashes `--` for words?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21852/single-dashes-for-single-character-options-but-double-dashes-for-words).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a pretty consistent utility like Git, the rule is that single-letter switches are `-` and longer switches (actual words) start with `--`.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a general Unix-like-system feature, which became common with GNU applications: single dash options are "short" options and double-dash options are "long" options.  Short options can usually be combined, e.g., `git checkout -qf` means the same as `git checkout -q -f`.  See, e.g., [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/402377/1256452).  Various languages have library routines to parse short and/or long options (for instance, C has `getopt()` and often a variant spelled `getopt_long()`; [Python's `argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) has direct support for both short and long options).

Thus, one-letter option flags have one dash, and longer, name-like options have two.

Although this is not what you were asking, another related, generally-accepted practice is that `--` by itself (with no subsequent long option) is treated as the end of the options.  This allows you to specify files named `-file` without using the typical alternative workaround of `./-file`.  Git adopts and extends this idea a bit: `--` separates things like branch names from things like file names.  Should you happen to have a file named `master` in a branch also named `master`, you can do:

```
git checkout master
```

to name the branch, and:

```
git checkout -- master
```

to name the file.  (This is pretty useful when writing shell scripts or git aliases, where you don't want a file-name argument to be accidentally taken as a branch name instead.)

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, Git uses the typical Linux-style flags. These are one dash for flags with a single character, such as `-s` or `-u`, and two dashes for flags with multiple characters, like `--soft` or `--hard`.