# How to delete Git tag named starting with dash?

Tags: git

I tried deleting the git tag name which is named as `-d` using command 
`git tag -d -d` but couldn't able to delete it.

Any ideas?

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20169133/720999).

Answer (score 6):

`git tag -d -- -d` is the usual way to tell a *nix program that the argument after `--` is not an option but rather a positional argument.  This is how you can remove files named `-f` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

```
git tag -d -- -d
```

did not work for me.

However this did work:

```
git tag -d `git tag -l '*-d*'`
```

Explanation:

- List tags matching `*-d*`
- Pass resulting list to `git tag -d`

Comment: Care should be taken when using this method, as it will match all tags with `-d` *anywhere* in the tag name. It will delete the tag `-d`, but users may want to check the output of `git tag -l '*-d*'` first, before accidentally deleting that vital `foo-dot` (or similar) tag.

Comment: Good point.  In my case the tag actually had some kind of whitespace in it, so `git tag -l '-d'` returned nothing.  I had to put the `*` characters in the string in order for it to find the tag.

Comment: Useful answer, saves some time, though agree with first comment. +1'ed