# How to delete remote tag starting with minus

Tags: git, tags

I am not able to delete tag starting with minus sign

```
git push origin :refs/tags/-a
```

It is showing warning.

> remote: warning: Deleting a non-existent ref.

Locally it gets deleted using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711383/how-to-delete-git-tag-named-starting-with-dash).

Comment: What about `git push --delete origin -- -a`?

Comment: There are no "remote tags", there are just "tags". If you send a request to the remote, to delete (from its repository) the tag reference `refs/tags/-a` and it does not *have* `refs/tags/-a`, I would say that you are all done.

Comment: @torek It's still showing in stash repo after executing above scenario.

Comment: @1615903 Its displaying: `remote ref does not exists`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "stash repo". Atlassian Stash? Git's `git stash save`?

Comment: @torek I mean in Atlassian stash server.

Comment: Atlassian has some kind of fancy GUI front end they paste over Git. I know very little about that. If the remote ref is gone and the local ref is gone, they're just showing some sort of ghost. If at least one ref still exists, that's the ref you need to delete.