# Correct usage of bash getopts using long options

Tags: bash, getopts

I have written below code for using long options with `getopts`, but it doesn't work (arguments have no effect on values of the variables). What is the correct syntax?

```
while getopts "c:(mode)d:(file1)e:(file2)" opt; do
  case $opt in
  -c|--mode)
      mode=$OPTARG
      ;;  
  -d|--file1)
      file1=$OPTARG
      ;;  
  -e|--file2)
      file2=$OPTARG
      ;;  
  esac
done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that the code in question is for `ksh` and not `bash`. For `getopts` we can't use long options. I ended up manually parsing arguments as below

```
while test -n "$1"; do
    case "$1" in
      -c|--mode)
          mode=$2
          shift 2
          ;;  
      -d|--file1)
          file1=$2
          shift 2
          ;;  
      -e|--file2)
          file2=$2
          shift 2
          ;;  
    esac
done
```

Comment: Actually, that's how I do it all the time; I typically have a `*)` case which leaves the loop, so arguments can be parsed after the options.