# Handling flags for a shell script without getopts

Tags: shell, posix

I have created a script for `/bin/sh` posix shell that handles flags using the `getopts` utility, now I realized that it's probably not the best choice in my case, it's an external dependency and in the end it's not even that flexible, it's probably good for flags that are 1 char long, but I would like to use more "verbose" and intuitive flags like `--config` or `--value-for-a=42` .

Assuming that I would like to implement something that is self contained, what is the alternative ?

Comment: `getopts` is a shell built-in, not an external dependency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in the `sh` shell ? are you sure ? anyway I have to use longer flags

Comment: Rolling your own system will be hard work to do well, and generally is not a good idea.  If you must do it, model it on the GNU extended `getopt` program (which in turn is based on the GNU `getopt()` and `getopt_long()` functions).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you expand on that with a complete post ? What do you mean with "it's not a good idea" and how to handle longer flags with `getopts` ?

Comment: It depends which `sh` you're referring to; you need to identify your platform and your shell more precisely.  All the POSIX-ish shells I know of have `getopts` built in — Bash, Korn Shell, Z Shell.  Archaic Bourne shell might not; System V Bourne shell did.  As to expanding my comments into an answer — no, the proposed duplicate already covers the subject in extenso.

Answer (score 1):

This is one quick and dirty method:

```
AAA=default
# example: BBB left unspecified so you can optionally override from environment
XYZ=${XYZ:-0}   # optional so you could override from environment
ABC=${ABC:-0}
while test $# -gt 0 ; do

  # switches
  if test "$1" = "--flag-xyz" ; then XYZ=1 ; shift ; continue; fi
  if test "$1" = "--flag-abc" ; then ABC=1 ; shift ; continue; fi

  # options with arguments
  case "$1" in
  --option-aaa=*) AAA="${1##--option-aaa=}" ; shift; continue; break ;;
  --option-bbb=*) BBB="${1##--option-bbb=}" ; shift; continue; break ;;
  esac

  # unknown - up to you - positional argument or error?
  echo "Unknown option $1"
  shift
done
```

Customise as required.

The advantage of this method is it is order independent, you can tweak options for edge cases in your syntax if needed. And it is simple otherwise.

If you need to enforce ordering break the processing into multiple statements with a break from the relevant while statement when needed.

Downside is there is a bit of the duplication that getopt sometimes avoids.

EDIT: change [==] and -gt to test

Comment: this script mainly works for the `bash` it's not really for the `sh`.

Comment: I thought I just tested it on sh 

(digs around)

Sneaky, the Linux I have in front of me symlinks /usr/bin/sh --> /bin/bash

Couldn't you use the same approach though, just the syntax would be a bit different?

Comment: Looking at http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sh sh supports case, shift, esac, break, continue $# and ${##} - so presumably just '==' thats missing? edit happening...

Comment: I think that the evaluation with `:` it's likely to break in a `sh` compliant shell, for example `{ABC:-0}` it's likely to be not compatible with `sh`.

Comment: You could be right. That bit was just gold plating though ;-)

Comment: FWIW `${ABC:-0}` is POSIX compliant.