# How to use getopt with this several values?

Tags: bash, sh, getopt

I try to achieve a script with multi options. I started with the [doc](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/getopt1.html), get some errors, went to the browser. Read some links and find this on SO : [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options).

So I read it and rewrote my script. I made a mistake somewhere. Where am I wrong ?

**SH**

```
#!/bin/sh

TEMP=`getopt -o vfts: --long verbose,format,type,style: \
             -n 'opt2' -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Terminating..." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

eval set -- "$TEMP"

VERBOSE=false
FORMAT=
TYPE=
STYLE=
while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -v | --verbose ) VERBOSE=true; shift ;;
        -f | --format ) FORMAT="$2"; shift 2 ;;
        -t | --type ) TYPE="$2"; shift 2 ;;
        -s | --style ) STYLE="$2"; shift 2 ;;
        -- ) shift; break ;;
        -*) break ;;
        * ) break ;;
    esac
done

echo "verbose = $VERBOSE"
echo "format = $FORMAT"
echo "type = $TYPE"
echo "style = $STYLE"
```

**Output**

```
> ./opt2.sh -v -f fofo -t toto -s soso

verbose = true // ok
format = -t // should be fofo
type =  // should be toto
style = soso // ok
```

Comment: run your script `sh -x ./opt2.sh .....`

Comment: not if I use a chmod +x on opt2.sh.

Comment: @aloisdg the `-x` that Kevin referred to does not mean execute, it sets the xtrace shell option which will cause each statement executed by the shell script to be printed to the console. In that way you can see where your script is going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options string is wrong, it should be `vf:t:s:`. The colon indicates a required argument which each of your options except for v has. Also need to adjust your long options string accordingly.

Comment: `verbose,format:type:style:` I guess ? I will try now.

Comment: I think you're missing a few commas there

Comment: Where I am missing a few commas ? It works perfectly like this. Should I add missing commas ?

Comment: @aloisdg, wich meant `verbose,format:,type:,style:` which is more readable/maintainable, even though it appears you don't require a comma after a colon.

Comment: @aloisdg did you test the long options with the script without the commas?

Answer (score 2):

You could have done some debugging yourself, quite easily:

```
$ set -- -v -f fofo -t toto -s soso
$ TEMP=$(getopt -o vfts: --long verbose,format,type,style: -- "$@")
$ echo "$TEMP"
 -v -f -t -s 'soso' -- 'fofo' 'toto'
```

Hmm, your `-f` and `-t` arguments are disconnected. Make them required

```
$ TEMP=$(getopt -o vf:t:s: --long verbose,format:,type:,style: -- "$@")
$ echo "$TEMP"
 -v -f 'fofo' -t 'toto' -s 'soso' --
```

---

To demonstrate that the commas apparently are not strictly required in the --long definition:

```
$ TEMP=$(getopt -o vf:t:s: --long verbose,format:type:style: -- "$@")
$ echo $?; echo "$TEMP"
0
 -v -f 'fofo' -t 'toto' -s 'soso' --
```

Comment: Did not think about it, but yes !