# Using getopt to parse long arguments skips to the first value

Tags: bash, getopt

I am trying to use `getopt` to parse long arguments (some of which are compulsory and others that are not). The code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# firstName is compulsory, age is not and lastName is again compulsory.

OPTS=`getopt --long firstName:,age::,lastName: -n 'longArgumentsParsing' -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Failed parsing options." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

#echo "$OPTS"
eval set -- "$OPTS"

while true; do
  echo "Argument seen: $1";
  echo "And value seen: $2";
  case "$1" in

    --firstName ) echo "First name: $2"; shift 2;
        ;;

    --lastName )
        echo "Last Name: $2";
        shift 2;
        ;;

    --age ) if [ -z "$2" ];
            then
              echo "Age is not specified.";
            else
              echo "Age specifed: $2"; shift 2;
            fi
            ;;

    -- ) shift; break ;;

    * ) break ;;
  esac
done
```

Every time I run it with `./longArgumentsParsing --firstName sriram --age 30` the program exits with the following output:

```
Argument seen: sriram
And value seen: --lastName
```

The program is clearly unable to parse the input key and argument value pairs properly. Why? Where am I going wrong?

UPDATE:

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22459338/350685), I tried to debug this myself: 
On the command line:
`set -- --firstName sriram --lastName shankar`
and then:
`OPTS=$(getopt -l firstName:,lastName:  -- "$@");`
To get the output:
`echo $?; echo "$OPTS"`
`0
 'sriram' --lastName 'shankar' --`

My questions:
1. How can I get the above to be correct?
2. I have removed the optional argument (which I do not want to do), and am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in the above code:

1. The script parses only long arguments. The correct invocation of `getopt`, in case one is using only long arguments is the following:

> OPTS=$(getopt -o '' -l "firstName:,lastName:,age::" -- "$@");

Note the `''` next to the `-o` flag. Getopt requires that the `-o` flag be left blank in case there are no short-form arguments.

2. Arguments to this script need to be specified with the `=` sign.
   A sample invocation of the script would be:
   `./longArgumentsParsing.bash --firstName=sriram --lastName=shankar --age=30`.