# How do i add options in my script Unix

Tags: unix

```
$ ./test1.sh <option> root/test/

-f -- display all ordinary files
-x -- display only executable files
-l -- display only links
-d -- display all the directories
```

So i want this to be my out put, but have i no idea how to make options in my script, any suggestions?

Comment: You can access the command line parameters in a bash shell script with `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)