# getopt on linux and solaris

Tags: solaris, getopt

On linux the following operation with getopt works fine:

```
TEMP=`getopt :mvfuhr:: --long "mask,verbose,force,unmask, help, remask::" -n  'test.sh' -- "$@"`
```

On Solaris, i am unable use the long arguments to process...
Though the this works:

```
  TEMP=`getopt :mvfuhr:: "$@"`
```

Looks like the getopt  bundled with the solaris is of an older version. How can i make it work like linux? or is there some setting that needs to be done to process long arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a clever (although currently with a minor bug) way to handle this issue:

[Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/7680682#7680682)