# Bash getopts with non-alphabetical option

Tags: bash, getopts

I am trying to use getopts to parse some command-line arguments in bash version 4.2.45. Unfortunately when I run this script with -r1 apple -r2 banana -n hello -k 56 I do not get any output for r1 or r2. e.g.

```
./script.sh -r1 apple -r2 banana -n hello -k 56
hello 56
```

Below is script.sh

```
read1=
read2=
name=
ks=
outdir=
threads=
while getopts "r1:r2:n:k:o:t" OPTION
do
    case $OPTION in
        r1) read1="$OPTARG" ;;
        r2) read2="$OPTARG" ;;
        n) name="$OPTARG" ;;
        k) ks="$OPTARG" ;;
        o) outdir="$OPTARG" ;;
        t) threads="$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done

echo $read1 $read2 $name $ks
```

When I change r1->r and r2->x then I see:

```
apple banana hello 56
```

as I expected. Are digits really not allowed as options, or is there something else I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Short options with a single `-` can only be a single character. `r1:` creates a `-r` option and a `-1` option that takes an argument.

If you want long options then switch from `getopts` to `getopt` and use the `-l` option, which will allow you to use `--long` arguments with two dashes.

```
./script.sh --r1 apple --r2 banana -n hello -k 56
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried doing that and now I get `./script.sh: illegal option -- -
./script.sh: illegal option -- -`

Comment: Just to clarify, John is suggesting that you, Dave, switch from using bash's `getopts` to using an entirely separate external program called `getopt`.  `getopts` does not support long options but `getopt` does.  Some of the pros and cons of `getopt` along with a short example can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options).