# Bash - optional argument required but not passed for use in getopts

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

How do I flag an error in a bash script which requires an argument
for getopt, but the user didn't pass it? e.g. the script below
requires an argument for option "t":

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts "ht:" OPTION
do
    case $OPTION in
        h)
            echo "Hi"
            ;;
        t)
            echo You entered $OPTARG
            ;;
    esac
done
```

I want to catch the below error and print something else and
exit. Currently, it goes on to evaluate more arguments without
exiting.

```
$ ./x.sh -h -t aa     # (this is fine)
Hi
You entered aa

$ ./x.sh -h -t       # (this is not handled)
Hi
No arg for -t option      # (this error is being printed by bash)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several points here:

```
# Note the leading ':'
while getopts :ht: OPTION
do
    case $OPTION in
        h)
            echo "Hi"
            ;;
        t)
            echo "You entered $OPTARG"
            if [[ ${OPTARG:0:1} == '-' ]]; then
                echo "Invalid value $OPTARG given to -$OPTION" >&2
                exit 1
            fi
            ;;
        :)  echo "$0: -$OPTARG needs a value" >&2; 
            exit 2 
            ;;
        \?) echo "$0: unknown option -$OPTARG" >&2; 
            exit 3
            ;;
    esac
done
```

The leading ':' on the option list allows us to do our own error handling.  If an unknown option is supplied then `OPTION` is set to a `?`.  Note that in the `case` statement this has to be escaped (prefixed with a `\`), otherwise it would match any single character.

If a value is not supplied to an option, then `OPTION` is set to a `:`.  Unfortunately this does not help if someone does:

```
./x -t -h
```

since the `-h` will be taken as the `OPTARG` to option `-t`.  Hence the extra test.

Notice that all the error messages go to standard-error (`>&2`).  To halt the execution of the script we use `exit` followed by a number in the range 0-255.  The only number with a specific meaning is zero, which means success.  The numbers 1-255 can have any meaning that we choose, but all imply failure.

Using your examples:

```
./x.sh -t -h
You entered -h
Invalid value -h given to -t

./x.sh -h -t aa
Hi
You entered aa

./x.sh -h -t
Hi
./x.sh: -t needs a value

./x.sh -t tea -c
You entered tea
./x.sh: unknown option -c
```

Comment: Excellent answer, and it answers things I wanted to ask next. Thank you very much, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

When it gets a failure, `getopts` sets OPTION to a question mark (`?`).  You should add that to your case statement.  As noted, that is a shell globbing character, requiring escaping.

`getopts` is a built-in feature of `bash`.  Besides checking for the explicit `?` character, you can also use the `bash` variable `OPTERR` as mentioned in *[Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)*.

The best place to find this information is in `bash`'s documentation. Oddly enough (given the number of extensions in `bash`), it is in a section titled *[4.1 Bourne Shell Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)*, and indeed there is a [POSIX getopts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/getopts.html) for reference.  The `OPTERR` variable, however, is a [`bash` extension](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables).

Comment: Thanks for these links and help.