# Bash long options/flags - how to do it?

Tags: bash, shell, getopt, getopts, getopt-long

I am trying to change my working script with getopts to getopt ( long flags ).
Below i present my code which is working.

```
getopts 'm:' mode
modeValue=$OPTARG

getopts 'p:' parameter
parameterValue=$OPTARG

getopts 'u:' parameter
parameterValue2=$OPTARG

getopts 'l:' parameter 
parameterValue3=$OPTARG

getopts 'n:' parameter 
parameterValue4=$OPTARG

getopts 'e:' parameter 
parameterValue5=$OPTARG

getopts 'w:' parameter 
parameterValue6=$OPTARG

getopts 'r:' parameter 
parameterValue7=$OPTARG

case $modeValue in
    addRepository)
          doAddRepository "$parameterValue" "$parameterValue7"
          exit $?
        ;;
    addProject)
          doAddProject "$parameterValue"
          exit $?
        ;;
    addUser)
          doAddUser "$parameterValue2" "$parameterValue4" "$parameterValue5" "$parameterValue6"
          exit $?
        ;;
    assignProject)
          doAssignProject "$parameterValue" "$parameterValue2" "$parameterValue3"
          exit $?
        ;;
    *)
          #echo "$doShowUsage"    
          exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Now my script is working like example below:

```
For add repository: ./script.sh -m addRepository -p NameOfTheProject -r NameOfTheRepository
```

I want to edit this for something like this:

```
./script.sh --mode addRepository --project NameOfTheProject --repo NameOfTheRepository
```

I started to modify code and added something what i present below:

```
 TEMP=`getopt -o m:p:u:l:n:e:c:r: --long mode:,project:,username:,level:,name:,email:,pass:,repo: -n 'test.sh'
    -- "$@"` eval set -- "$TEMP"

while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -m|--mode)
            case "$2" in
                addRepository)
                        doAddRepository=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
                addProject)
                        doAddProject=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
                addUser)
                        doAddUser=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
                assignProject)
                        doAssignProject=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
                esac ;;
        -h|--help)
            case "$2" in
                *) echo "$doShowUsage"
                   exit 1
                esac ;;
        esac done
```

My question is : Am I doing it in the right way ? How can I add parameters to the functions "doAddProject/Repository/User...?" Can someone give me some advices? Above functions got different amount of parameters so take a look at it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Stephane Chazelas wrote a very fine [getops-long shell script](https://sourceforge.net/p/bashdb/code/ci/master/tree/getopts_long.sh#l5) that I use in my [bash debugger](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/). You can copy that script and use it.

If you run that program setting variable `test_getopts_long`, e.g.

```
test_getopts_long=1 bash getopts_long.sh
```

you'll see extensive examples for how to use, and it tests itself.