# Bash script with getopt - long options

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, flags, getopt

so far i have edited my script and it doesn't work as i would like to.

Firstly i will present this code:

```
    while true ; do
      case "$1" in
        --mode)
           MODE=$2
           shift 2;         
           ;;
        -l|--login)
           LOGIN=$2 
           shift 2;
           ;;
        -e|--email) 
           EMAIL=$2
           shift 2; 
           ;;
        -r|--repo)
           REPO=$2
           shift 2; 
           ;;
        -p|--project)
           PROJ="$2"
           shift 2;
           ;;
       -h|--help)
           echo "$doShowUsage"
           exit 1
   esac
   break
done

if [ "$MODE" == "doAddRepository" ]; then
        echo " CREATING REPOS!!!"
    doAddRepository "$PROJ" "$REPO"
fi

if [ "$MODE" == "doAddProject" ]; then
    doAddProject "$PROJ"
fi
```

As you can see above when i write in cli:

```
./script.sh --mode doAddProject -p test
```

It will not work but when i change the code for:

```
  if [ "$MODE" == "doAddProject" ]; then
    doAddProject "$2"
fi
```

Then it works! My question is how to connect with my functions ? I present below 2 of the functions.

```
doAddRepository{
local projectName=$1
local repoName=$2
...
}

doAddProject{
local projectName=$1
...
}

TEMP=`getopt -o m:p:r:h --long mode:,project:,repo:,help -n 'script.sh' -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$TEMP"
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options

Comment: I saw this link but i can't find this thing that's why i ask in my topic about it...

Comment: @Hema, I dont know why you mentioned the link in you comment

Comment: @adamos, please change the title, you are not using getopt in this script

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is iterating only once because of the out of place `break` statement. You should break the loop only if the argument is empty.

```
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        --mode)
            MODE=$2
            shift 2;         
            ;;
        -l|--login)
            LOGIN=$2 
            shift 2;
            ;;
        -e|--email) 
            EMAIL=$2
            shift 2; 
            ;;
        -r|--repo)
            REPO=$2
            shift 2; 
            ;;
        -p|--project)
            PROJ="$2"
            shift 2;
            ;;
       -h|--help)
            echo "$doShowUsage"
            exit 1
            ;;
        '')
            break
            ;;
   esac
done
```