# osx Terminal / Shell Script function modifier

Tags: macos, shell

I am currently shell scripting and I would like to know how to make a - option while making a function. When you would execute a command similar to the following:

```
test -f
```

Here is the function I am using:

```
function test()
{
      echo $1;
      echo $2;
}
```

How could I add a -t for echo twice option?

Input:

```
 test -t Hello
```

Output:

```
  Hello
  Hello
```

I am using iTerm and oh-my-zsh.

Thanks, base2101

Comment: Look up how to use [`getopts`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/).

Comment: I didn't know the keyword getops. You can close it if you want.

Comment: Technically, [`getopts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-getopts) is a (built-in) command rather than a keyword.  This link is to the Bash manual rather than an SO question, though.

Comment: Please don't name your function `test` -- that's the name of a rather important standard command, and if you override it you may break some scripts etc in very strange ways.