# Why does '-1' not work in Awk but '(-1)' does?

Tags: awk, gnu, gawk

I was doing some data filtering and noticed something a bit strange.

As we all know, `awk '1'` is short for `awk '{print $0}'`, since `1` evaluates to True and triggers that default action on Awk, which consists on printing the current record.

Similarly, `awk '0'` does not print anything because it evaluates to False.

```
$ seq 3 | awk '0'
                      # nothing
$ seq 3 | awk '1'
1
2                     # everything
3
```

So I tried different approaches on this and noticed that `awk '-1'` gives an error, while `awk '(-1)'` works without a problem:

```
$ seq 3 | awk '-1'
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:      GNU long options: (standard)
...
        # all the gawk explanation on how to use it
...
$ seq 3 | awk '(-1)'
1
2                     # everything, since apparently
3                     # -1 evaluates to True
```

The same with `awk '-NF'` or `awk '-NR'` or any other expression starting with the negative character.

Why is this?

I am on GNU Awk 4.1.65, API: 2.0.

Comment: not strictly an issue with awk... just how options are processed... try `seq 3 | awk -- '-1'` and `seq 3 | grep '-1'` .. there's an duplicate somewhere..

Comment: @Sundeep: I agree with you, `awk '-1' ` will be interpreted as option `-1` that does not exist therefore the help page is displayed, however I can not explain the behavior of `seq 3 | awk '(-1)'` would bash interpret `(-1)`?

Comment: @Allan since `-` is not first character, `'(-1)'` is no longer considered as option.. so then it comes to awk.. `()` is useful in expression in case of operator precedence, clarity etc.. here, it just evaluates to `-1`

Comment: @Sundeep thanks for seeing what the error is!

Comment: also, in case someone's wondering, `awk '1'` is same as `awk 1`.. the quotes are used to avoid having to deal with shell special characters like   space, `$`, globs, etc and a typical awk one liner is gonna have those.... `awk '-1'` is same as `awk -1` ...

Comment: @fedorqui fair enough, will try to search duplicate for that.. I don't know if this is specific to GNU tools as well.. I don't know how these tools are written, I'm guessing they'll be using modules like getopts.. in short, any non-option argument starting with `-` will require special attention unless the tool has a way to distinguish it..

Comment: @fedorqui does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495669/difference-between-terms-option-argument-and-parameter

Comment: @Sundeep it explains it very well. Since it is not straightforward, would you mind answering with a little post explaining the issue and linking to that other question? I will of course vote to close as dupe of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
seq 3 | awk '-1'
```

is same as

```
seq 3 | awk -1
```

single/double quotes can be used to construct an argument on command line depending on what's needed, for ex:

```
$ echo 'foo baz' | grep 'foo b'
foo baz
$ echo 'foo baz' | grep foo\ b
foo baz

$ echo 'foo:baz:123' | awk '-F:' '{print $1}'
foo
$ f='-F:'; echo 'foo:baz:123' | awk "$f" '{print $1}'
foo
$ var='$1'; echo 'foo:baz:123' | awk '-F:' "{print $var}"
foo
```

Coming back to `awk -1`, the `-1` gets treated as an option (because options start with `-` or `--` depending on tool). `-1` is not a valid option, so we get an error

Most tools have a workaround for such cases, using `--` will indicate no further option

```
$ seq 3 | awk -- -1
1
2
3
```

More examples:

```
$ # echo is fine with echoing non-options starting with -
$ echo '-1'
-1
$ echo '-1' | grep '-1'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
$ echo '-1' | grep -- '-1'
-1

$ echo 'Foo' | grep 'foo'
$ # using option at end depends on tool, I think it is GNU specific
$ echo 'Foo' | grep 'foo' -i
Foo
$ echo 'Foo' | grep -- 'foo' -i
grep: -i: No such file or directory
```

Further reading: [Difference between terms: "option", "argument", and "parameter"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495669/difference-between-terms-option-argument-and-parameter)

Comment: You can also mention `var='$1'; echo 'foo:baz:123' | awk '-F:' "{print $var}"`, where the expression in Awk is within double quotes so it expands the Bash variable in it.