# Why is . passed as argument to npm without -- delimiter?

Tags: reactjs, npm, arguments, npm-scripts, react-scripts

I am having trouble figuring out why is `npm` taking `.` without `--` delimiter.

In the following command `.` is passed to `test` script without `--` delimiter.

```
npm test .
```

`test` script is defined in `package.json` like this:

`"test": "react-app-rewired test"`

**Passing regular argument to `test` script**

This happened to me when I tried to pass `--coverage` to `npm test` but later i found out that to pass arguments to npm script i need `--` before any following argument.

This is what works if i want to pass argument:

```
npm test -- --coverage
```

But this is will not pass `--coverage` argument

```
npm test --coverage
```

Question is why is `.` being passed without `--`. Based on npm documentation to pass any argument to a script we need to use `--` delimiter and npm will know that the following flags/arguments are for `test` script or any other script that we want to parametrize.

Comment: Can you clarify where exactly you're receiving/not receiving those arguments? How do you figure that one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: I edited my question to give more context. Tell me if this makes more sense.

Comment: Be aware of the difference between positional parameters and options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495669/difference-between-terms-option-argument-and-parameter/36495940

Comment: Aha. If i get ti correctly, `.` is an option for `npm` command? But in my case it is also a parameter for test command that is wrapped by `npm test`

Comment: Essentially, a period (`.`) is not interpreted as an option because it does not begin with a hyphen (`-`).

Comment: Ah i get it, I added some random characters and it was passed down like this `npm test somethinElse` and it ran like `react-app-rewired test somethingElse`.

Comment: I'll let someone else compose an answer and review it. If there is none soon, i will compile comments here into an answer. There is a question from someone else that is related to my question here that will be answered also after this. Thanks for your comments, they cleared things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) explains in his answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046885/what-does-do-when-running-an-npm-command) (*emphasis* mine):

> *double hyphens* *(*`--`*)* as an argument on its own is standardized across
> all UNIX commands: It means that further arguments should be treated
> as positional *parameters*, not options.

To answer your question:
`.` is passed as positional parameter to the `react-app-rewired` script because you provide it as positional parameter when running `npm test .`.
`--something` would be interpreted by npm as an option for itself unless it is prefixed with `--` at some point, in which case it will as well be treated as positional parameter.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495669/difference-between-terms-option-argument-and-parameter/36495940) for a more detailed explanation of the difference between command options, arguments and parameters.

Comment: You say; _"Thus npm `test .` is equivalent to `npm test -- --.` and `npm test -- --coverage` would be equivalent to `npm test coverage`"_. However neither of the comparable examples that you've given are equivalent. In the case of your first example the consuming script/command will receives either; `.` or `--.`. In the case of your second example the consuming script/command will receive either; `--coverage` or `coverage`.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing this out. I believe the updated version should be correct

Comment: @whme  To test your assumption I suggest defining the `test` script in _package.json_ as `"test": "node test.js"`. In _test.js_ add the following line of code `console.log(process.argv);`. It logs an array of cmd line args that the script receives by utilizing [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv). You'll see that your updated comparisons are also not equivalent. The `'--.'` in `npm test '--.'` and `'--coverage'` in `npm test '--coverage'` are consumed by npm _(not passed to the script/cmd)_ because they too begin with a hyphen even though they're quoted.