# Should I be using parameters or export environment variables?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've always developed my shell scripts using parameters, on a daily-basis or even when developing some automation scripts. However, recently I've tried a different approach, exporting environment variables to my scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash

: ${USER?"Requires USER"}
: ${FIRST_NAME?"Requires FIRST_NAME"}
: ${LAST_NAME?"Requires LAST_NAME"}
: ${EMAIL?"Requires EMAIL"}

set -x

setup_git_account(){
  su - "${USER}" -c "git config --global user.name '${FIRST_NAME} ${LAST_NAME}'"
  su - "${USER}" -c "git config --global user.email '${EMAIL}'"
}

setup_git_account
```

This ensures a smaller code, easy checks if all the required variables are initialized and also, better understanding of what the script is doing, once all the variables are declared on outside.

```
export USER='john' && export FIRST_NAME='John' && export LAST_NAME='Doe' && export EMAIL='john.doe@email.com' && setup_git_account.sh
```

Which could be represented like this if implemented with receiving parameters:

```
setup_git_account.sh --user 'john' --firstname 'John' --lastname 'Doe' --email 'john.doe@email.com'
```

However, the last one, would need way more lines of code to implement the `getopts` switch case, check the passed parameters values, etc.

Anyway, I know we're used to the second approach, but I think the first approach also has several benefits. And I would like to hear more from you, if there's any downside between the presented approaches. And which one should I be using ?

Thanks!

Comment: With environment variables there's obviously a higher chance of unexpected behavior if not all of them are always set explicitly. They can be set (accidentially) by the system, your bashrc, a script you ran before etc.

Comment: I would recommend using parameters

Comment: Use lower-case variable names. `USER`, in particular, is already in use and *will* be set in your environment already.

Comment: It would be a major drawback design if all the utilities used environment variables instead of arguments: if two utilities used the same variable name, say `foo`; if you call the first one like `foo=bar utility1`, and then `utility1` needs to call `utility2` without `foo`, then `utility1` would need to unset `foo`. While `utility1` can handle its own variables, things get trickier if `utility1` doesn't know that `utility2` also calls `utility3` that uses a variable `baz` also used by `utility1`. It would be a nightmare to handle! The current design is much safer as it provides some isolation.

Comment: It would also be more difficult to chain utilities. `find` comes to mind. How would you deal with `find ... \( -sometest -exec utility1 -someoption {} \; \) -o \( -someothertest -exec utility1 -someotheroption {} \; \)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Indeed would be a nightmare! Thank you for pointing that out, I haven't thought about that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your values is optional; I would just use positional parameters.

```
: ${1?"Requires USER"}
: ${2?"Requires FIRST_NAME"}
: ${3?"Requires LAST_NAME"}
: ${4?"Requires EMAIL"}

sudo -u "$1" git config --global user.name "$2 $3" user.email "$4"
```

Providing the way for the user to specify values in an arbitrary order is just an unnecessary complication.

You would simply call the script with

```
setup_git_account.sh 'john' 'John' 'Doe' 'john.doe@email.com'
```

Reconsider whether the first and last names need to be separate arguments. They are combined into a single argument to `git config` by the script anyway; just take the name as a single argument as well.

```
setup_git_account.sh 'john' 'John Doe' 'john.doe@email.com'
```

(with the appropriate changes to the script as necessary).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

A bit off-topic, the invocation syntax with environment variables for `bash` can be shorter, no need for `export`'s:

```
USER='john' FIRST_NAME='John' LAST_NAME='Doe' EMAIL='john.doe@email.com' setup_git_account.sh
```

Comment: This is a good answer. The question of environment-variables-vs-parameters is a bit opinion-based, but this is the right way to call the script if environment variables are used.

Answer (score 0):

I never use your approach. I think there are no drawbacks by using parameters. It's a common way to use parameters and if you are using longopts there are self-descriptive. 
In my opinion env vars are a solution if you need data in different scripts.

Maybe you have problems to run such a script on systems where you don't be allowed to change the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've parameterized your variables using a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/28466267#28466267) I wrote a while back and even added `--help`.

This solution accepts environment variables as well as options (which will trump the variables):

```
while getopts e:f:hl:u:-: arg; do
  case "$arg" in
    e )  EMAIL="$OPTARG" ;;
    f )  FIRST_NAME="$OPTARG" ;;
    h )  do_help ;;
    l )  LAST_NAME="$OPTARG" ;;
    u )  USER_NAME="$OPTARG" ;;
    - )  LONG_OPTARG="${OPTARG#*=}"
         case $OPTARG in
           email=?* )   EMAIL="$LONG_OPTARG" ;;
           first*=?* )  FIRST_NAME="$LONG_OPTARG" ;;
           help* )      do_help ;;
           last*=?* )   LAST_NAME="$LONG_OPTARG" ;;
           user=?* )    USER_NAME="$LONG_OPTARG" ;;
           * ) echo "Illegal option/missing argument: --$OPTARG" >&2; exit 2 ;;
         esac ;;
    * )  exit 2 ;; # error messages for short options already given by getopts
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

HELP=" - see ${0##*/} --help"
: ${USER_NAME?"Requires USER_NAME$HELP"}
: ${FIRST_NAME?"Requires FIRST_NAME$HELP"}
: ${LAST_NAME?"Requires LAST_NAME$HELP"}
: ${EMAIL?"Requires EMAIL$HELP"}

su - "$USER_NAME" -c "git config --global user.name '$FIRST_NAME $LAST_NAME'"
su - "$USER_NAME" -c "git config --global user.email '$EMAIL'"
```

Note that I changed `$USER` to `$USER_NAME` to avoid conflicts with your local environment (`$USER` is *your* user name on your local Linux system!)

You can also extract the user's full name from the system:

```
FULL_NAME="$(getent passwd |awk -v u="$USER_NAME" -F: '$1 == u { print $5 }')"
```

(I see no reason to separate FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME; what do you do for Jean Claude Van Damme?  They're only used together anyway.  Also note that not all users will have full names in the passwd file.)

This uses `do_help` to show the `--help` output.  Here's an example of how that could look (I'd put this at the vary top of the script so somebody just reading it can get the synopsis; it's not in the above code block because I wanted to prevent the block from getting a scroll bar):

```
do_help() { cat <</help
Usage: ${0##*/} [OPTIONS]
  -u USER_NAME,  --user=USER_NAME
  -f FIRST_NAME, --firstname=FIRST_NAME
  -l LAST_NAME,  --lastname=LAST_NAME
  -e EMAIL,      --email=EMAIL
Each option may also be passed through the environment as e.g. $EMAIL

Code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515444/519360
/help
}
```