# getopts options with same starting alphabet

Tags: bash, getopts

I am using `getopts` to pass parameters to a shell script.

For example, I want to make operations on two sections in the script, that both start with the same letter. I also dont want to choose any other letter. For example I have two projects : project 1 and  project2 and both of them start with the letter p.

Is there any way, that I can provide full strings such as `--project1` etc. Or is there any other solution?

```
while getopts "project1 project2" opt;
# This ofcourse would not work. So, whats the solution?
```

Is there any alternative to `getopts`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an options argument. It should look something like

```
while getopts p: flag
do
    case $flag in
        p ) OARG=$OPTARG;;
    esac
done

echo $OARG
```

`getopts` stores the option passed in in `OPTARG`.

You would invoke the script using

```
./script.sh -p "project1"
```

Comment: project1 and project2 are not mutually exclusive. sometimes, it might be required to run them both at the same time. Maybe my example project1 and project2 was not correct.

Comment: In that case you would probably want to use `getopt` (no s)