# Read parameter from custom option in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to create a bash script and take in 2 options

- bePort and fePort

since this is working

```
while getopts ":a:b:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered!, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    b)
      echo "-b was triggered!, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

I run

`bash test.sh -a aaa -b bbb`

I got

```
-a was triggered!, Parameter: aaa
-b was triggered!, Parameter: bbb
```

---

So then, I've tried this

```
while getopts ":fe:be:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    fe)
      echo "-fe was triggered!, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    be)
      echo "-be was triggered!, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I run

`bash test.sh -fe 4444 -be 3333`

I got nothing printing in my prompt.

I was expecting to see something like this

```
-be was triggered!, Parameter: 3333
-fe was triggered!, Parameter: 4444
```

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: If you want to handle `-fe` as a single option, consider using the pattern described in [BashFAQ #35](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) instead of `getopts` to build your own parsing.

Comment: ...that said, this is not standard practice -- see [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), specifically guideline #5: *One or more options without option-arguments, followed by at most one option that takes an option-argument, should be accepted when grouped behind one '-' delimiter.*; and guideline #3: *Each option name should be a single alphanumeric character (the alnum character classification) from the portable character set. The -W (capital-W) option shall be reserved for vendor options.*

Comment: to make a long story short... you get one letter

Comment: If you want long (multiletter) options, the standard is to use a double-dash and separate the value with "=" (as in `grep --color=always`). But `getopts` only handles single-letter options, so you need to use something else. Either that, or switch to single-letter options. Frankly, two-letter options are rather weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It because `-fe 4444` is parsed as `-f -e 4444`.

Test code:

```
while getopts ":fe:be:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    b)
      echo "-b was triggered!, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    e)
      echo "-e was triggered!, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    f)
      echo "-f was triggered!, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    fe)
      echo "-fe was triggered!, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    be)
      echo "-be was triggered!, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Output:

```
$ bash test.sh -fe 4444 -be 3333
-f was triggered!, Parameter: 
-e was triggered!, Parameter: 4444
-b was triggered!, Parameter: 
-e was triggered!, Parameter: 3333
```

---

It is appropriate to use long options like `--fe 4444`.
How to parse long options with bash have been answered at another post.

-> [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)

Comment: what did you do that I didn't do ? could n't seem to spot it.

Comment: @kyo, the code here accepts `-f` and `-e` as separate options, which is how getopts handles `-fe` (as one `-f` followed by a `-e`). You'll notice that the `fe` and `be` cases are never called in the example output, but it has `-f` output, then `-e` output, then `-b` output, then `-e` output again.

Comment: Your code does not handle `be` and `fe` together that is my original question.

Comment: I stil wondering what is the best way to parse long option with bash...

Comment: @set0gut1 There is no built-in way. Either parse the argument completely manually (by iterating over `"$@"` yourself), or use a third-party library.