# How can I accept long arguments using getopts in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I'm trying to have my `getops` function run with multiple flags and arguments but instead of short (`-f` style) flag, I want to accept a long one (`--flag` style). For example:

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  usage >&2
  exit 1
else
  while $1 "hf:" opt; do
    case $opt in
       h)
          echo "Here is the help menu:"
          usage
          ;;
       f)
          ls -l $OPTARG >&2
          ;;
       \?)
          echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
          ;;
        :)
          echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument" >&2
          exit 1
          ;;
    esac
  done
fi
```

I would like the `-h` and `-f` to be `--help` and `--file` respectively.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to know how to use the existing `getopt`/`getopts` commands, or are you trying to write your own version of these? I've answered the former. If it's the latter, show us your code so far, and let us know what specifically you need help with.

Comment: Here's a solution, if you still want to use `getopts`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680682/8833540

Comment: What is the problem or question? Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: @jww - I think the question is written in a pretty clear manner . I simply asked how I can have my code support a --flag rather than the -<letter> formart. Please do no down vote questions for no logical reason

Comment: Don't take it personally, his goal in life is do run around editing and downvoting questions -- don't worry, it all comes out in the wash. (did you get `shift` figured out? -- e.g. it just consumes an argument (positional parameter) so that `$2` becomes `$1`, and so on..)

Answer (score 1):

`getopt` will do this for you. It handles short options, long options, options with and without arguments, `--` to end option parsing, and more.

Boilerplate usage looks like:

```
options=$(getopt -o hf: -l help,file: -n "$0" -- "$@") || exit
eval set -- "$options"

while [[ $1 != -- ]]; do
    case $1 in
        -h|--help) echo "help!"; shift 1;;
        -f|--file) echo "file! $2"; shift 2;;
        *) echo "bad option: $1" >&2; exit 1;;
    esac
done
shift

# Process non-option arguments.
for arg; do
    echo "arg! $arg"
done
```

Comment: getopt documentation: the man page, of course, and you may have [an example file](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/misc-utils/getopt-parse.bash) on your systems (for me it's /usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/getopt-parse.bash)

Comment: Thanks a lot @John Kugelman ! Do you mind explaining the first line and the usage of shift ?

Comment: The last shift is to get rid of `--`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - The suggested code does not work , I took it as is but it doesn't work

Comment: Oops. Try again. I messed up the first line in my previous edit.