# How to pass an argument in a .shell script file

Tags: linux, shell, sh

This is the first time i am trying to edit a .sh file on ubuntu

```
ng build @xyz--abc/my-${library}
```

I am trying to pass a flag `--build-optimizer=false`  but if i add it to end it is giving error `Unknown option: '--build-optimizer'`

Need some help on how can I add this flag.

Thanks

Comment: Where is `--build-optimizer` coming from? Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Usually commandline argument option parsing is implemented with either the bash builtin `getopts` or one of the platform specific `getopt` implementations. While `getopts` does not support parsing long commandline options the GNU `getopt` implementation does. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-to-process-long-and-short-command-line-options) points out in detail the differences between the corresponding implementations. For an example on how to use the bash builtin `getopts` I'll refer to the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#EX33).

In order to give you a correct answer it therefore depends on how the script you're trying to modify implements commandline option parsing.

Answer (score 0):

```
LS_OPTIONS=''

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    --color=*)
      colorarg="${1#*=}"
      LS_OPTIONS="${LS_OPTIONS} ${1}"
      ;;
    -a|--all)
      allarg="${1}"
      LS_OPTIONS="${LS_OPTIONS} ${1}"
      ;;
    *)
      printf "* Error: Invalid argument.*\n"
      exit 1
  esac
  shift
done


printf "all   val: %s\n\n" "$allarg"
printf "color val: %s\n\n" "$colorarg"

ls ${LS_OPTIONS}
```

Parses the arguments and passes them to the underlying `ls`. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

[image: demo]

Comment: actually I have a .sh file in which there are many a things, one line is   ng build @xyz--abc/my-${library}   and I need to pass an argument   --flag = true   in it. I dont know how to do that. I really appreciate your efforts

Comment: Just like I passed `--color=yes` argument in the `.sh` file above. Won't it work for you?