# Passing long and short CLI options with & without space

Tags: bash, shell, getopt, getopts, getopt-long

1. I wish to pass long and short CLI options. I have tried below for short options:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while getopts d:t:r: option 
   do
    case "${option}"
    in
    d) c_date=${OPTARG};;
    t) c_type=${OPTARG};;
    r) c_date_range=${OPTARG};;
    esac
   done
   shift $((OPTIND -1))

   echo "Date:"$c_date
   echo "Type:"$c_type
   echo "Range:"$c_date_range
   ```

How can I accept long options like --**d**ate, --**t**ype, --**r**ange?

2. The **r**ange option accepts 2 dates i.e. `-r 2019-01-01 2019-02-01` or `--range 2019-01-01 2019-02-01`. How can I accept these dates and save in separate variables?

Comment: Look into getopt --longoptions - it will give you building block for parsing long options. Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-to-process-long-and-short-command-line-options

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no support for 'getlong' to take 2 values (as per the range). Common alternative are (1) have two flags ('--from date --to date). (2) combine the two date into single parameter (2019-01-01:2019-02-01), and decode the range or (3) modify the case for 'r' to pick the next argument (explicitly move OPTIND). not easy, but possible