# Using getopts in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to use getopts in a Bash script as follows:

```
while getopts ":hXX:h" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    hXX ) Usage
      ;;
    h ) echo "You pressed Hey"
      ;;
    \? ) echo "Usage: cmd [-h] [-p]"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

The idea behind is that I want to have two flags `-h` or `--help` for allowing user to be able to use HELP in order to be guided how to use the script and another second flag which starts with `h` but its like `-hxx` where `x` is whatever.

How can I distinguish these two since even when I press `--hxx` flag it automatically executes help flag.  I think the order of presenting them in `getopt` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: `getopts` support  only single char options

Comment: I need the other option as well!

Comment: Don't use `getopts` then! Or implement parsing options!

Comment: Surely you can be creative enough to ensure you don't have two options starting with `h` in a two option script??

Comment: It's not about creativity, it is a specific task which requires this!
In addition there are not only two options, i displayed two just for illustration.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. Are you going to take more options than just `-h` `--help` and `--hxx`? If not, forget `getopt` and just use a `case` and `shift`

Comment: I will try this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The 'external' `getopt` program (NOT the bash built in `getopts`) has support for '--longoptions'. It can be used as a pre-procssor to the command line options, making it possible to consume long options with the bash built-in getopt (or to other programs that do not support long options).

See: [Using getopts to process long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-to-process-long-and-short-command-line-options) for more details.

```
#! /bin/bash

TEMP=$(getopt -l help -- h "$@")
eval set -- "$TEMP"
while getopts h-: opt ; do
        case "$opt" in
                h) echo "single" ;;
                -) case "$OPTARG" in
                        -help) echo "Double" ;;
                        *) echo "Multi: $OPTARG" ;;
                esac ;;
                *) echo "ERROR: $opt" ;;
        esac
done
```