# Why my bash function can't parse optional argument?

Tags: bash, getopt

> Each long option name in longopts may be followed by one colon to indicate it has a required argument, and by two colons to indicate it has an optional argument.

in `man bash`.

I wrote a bash function `optionarg`:

```
optionarg (){
    opts=$(getopt -o , --long name:,pass:: -- "$@")
    eval set -- "$opts"
    while true; do
        case "$1" in
            --name)
                name=$2
                echo  "name is " $name
                shift 2;;
            --pass)
                case "$2" in 
                    '')
                        echo "no pass argument"
                        shift 2;; 
                    *)
                        pass=$2
                        echo  "pass" $pass
                        shift 2;;
                esac;;               
            --)
                shift 1;;
            *)  break;;
        esac
    done }
```

Let test my optionarg here.
1.Assign no argument with `pass`.

```
optionarg --name tom --pass
name is  tom
no pass argument
```

2.Assign an argument `xxxx` with `pass`.

```
optionarg --name tom --pass xxxx
name is  tom
no pass argument
```

How to fix my  `optionarg` function to get such output?

```
optionarg --name tom --pass xxxx
name is  tom
pass xxxx
```

Comment: See also [Using getopts to process long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/402377/519360), including [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28466267/519360), which can accept long options with optional arguments and which doesn't require the external call to `getopt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i would do it with only `case`

```
optionarg () {
    while [[ $@ ]]; do
        case "$1" in
            --name|-n) name=$2;;
            --pass|-p) pass=$2;;
        esac               
        shift
    done
    echo "name=$name"
    echo "pass=$pass"
}
```

Usage

```
$ optionarg --name user --pass dfgd
name=user
pass=dfgd

$ optionarg -n user -p dfgd
name=user
pass=dfgd
```

Answer (score 4):

Long options use `=` to assign an optional value:

```
$ optionarg --name tom --pass=xxxx
name is  tom
pass xxxx
```

This is documented in `man getopt`:

> If the option has an optional argument,  it  must  be  written
>          directly  after the long option name, separated by `=`, if present (if you add the
>          `=` but nothing behind it, it is interpreted as if no argument was  present;  this
>          is  a  slight bug, see the **BUGS**).