# Bash long options getopts

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I wrote a bash script, how can i add a long options for example: `--verbose` along with `-v` option?

My second question is what is the difference between `while getopts :v` and  `while getopts v`, i've done some research and i still can't fully understand it.

I have tried it with `getopts` but not working, also heard that `getopt` is not the right choice.

```
while getopts ":v" option; do
  case $option in
    v) verbose=true;;
    ?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2 && exit 1;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt supports long options

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano the GNU version of `getopt` supports long options, but other versions don't, making it a compatibility nightmare. See [Complex Option Parsing on Greycat's BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing).

Comment: Do the answers to ["How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash) and [BashFAQ #35: "How can I handle command-line options and arguments in my script easily?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) answer your question?

Comment: which getopt variant are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using getopts to process long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-to-process-long-and-short-command-line-options)