bash scripting using getopts with a read input of multiple inputs on the same line
Been a long time since I scripted, but here's what I'm trying to do.
There are 5 or more inputs.
The person selects them on the line after starting the script,   like 1 2 3 4 5, I then run that through a case statement to execute specific functions.
I had something like this but it doesn't work. I tried different args for getopts but nothing seems to get it into the case statement.
read opt

while getopts ":1234567:" opt
do
    case "$opt" in
        1) print "you selected option 1" ;;
        2) print "you selected option 2" ;;
        3) print "you selected option 3" ;;
        4) print "you selected option 4" ;;
        5) print "you selected option 5" ;;

        # \?) echo "unknown Option -$OPTARG" ; exit ;;
        # :) echo "missing required parameter for Option -$OPTARG" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND -1))
print "Your value testing $opt"
}

Tried the above code, no luck

You have } at the end with no matching {

getopts processes the command-line arguments in $*, not user input.

If you want to turn the input into arguments, use set -- $opt

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script

read -ra opts will put each option into a separate element in an array named opts, so for o in "${opts[@]}"; do case $o in ... is probably more what you want than getopts.

Or maybe you want select?

Learn to use https://shellcheck.net and post only "corrrected code" with a notice (shellcheck approved or similar). AND "it's not working" is a bad description of your problem. Always post exact text of error messages. Glad you got a solution below. Good luck.

Here is some code that works:
#!/bin/bash

read -a data                                    # read data into array
while getopts ":1234567:" opt "${data[@]/#/-}"  # prepend '-' to each
do
    case "$opt" in
        1) echo "you selected option 1" ;;
        2) echo "you selected option 2" ;;
        3) echo "you selected option 3" ;;
        4) echo "you selected option 4" ;;
        5) echo "you selected option 5" ;;

        # \?) echo "unknown Option -$OPTARG" ; exit ;;
        # :) echo "missing required parameter for Option -$OPTARG" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND -1))
echo "Your value testing $opt"

The major problem with your implementation is that getopts wants arguments. These are things that begin with a dash. So, -s or -1 are arguments, whereas 1 is not. I modified the read command to read into an array, which allows me to use array substitution to prepend a - to each argument in the array before feeding the values to getopts. I also used unique variable names to reduce any possible confusion.
Also print is going to send a file to a printer - use echo or printf to put text on the screen.

Thank you, exactly what i was looking for.  Appreciate it.   and the explanation.

have 1 more question,  if i had more than 10 number   the getops only looks at single numbers,   how would that change for the getops

Please accept this as answering the question if you feel it does. As for handling numbers >= 10, I hope you see that getopts isn't the best tool to use here. As recommended by @ton, have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script for better implementations. Note that you can make your own version of an OPTIND index for handling optional arguments like you specify for the parameter "7", though I think that looks like a mistake. Alternately, in hex the value 'a' is 10 in decimal. getopts is limited to single characters.

As for another option for numbers >= 10, GNU getopt allows long parameters (of the --argument type [e.g: --10]) but I think that's getting even further afield from what you want. For the gory details, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-to-process-long-and-short-command-line-options

I think i was making it harder than it needed to be,  i changed it to the following since there are more than 10 options    my                                                                                              read -a my_options
(which could be  1 10 20 30)
len=${#my_options[*]}
i=0
while [ $i -lt $len ]
do
echo $i
echo $len
case "${my_options[$i]}" in
